# Subversion: Change working directory's target repo

Tags: svn

I know, other RCS are better, but...

I have moved an SVN repository from file:///path/to/repo to http://host.name/svn/repo
but there is a working directory (checkout out from file://) with changes that want commiting to the http location.

How then, can I change the repo a working directory will commit to when issuing `svn commit`?

I'd rather do that than checkout a new copy and sync changes locally. Also, handy to know for the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like `svn switch` command is what you need:

```
svn switch --relocate FROM_PATH TO_PATH
```

Answer (score 4):

SVN `switch` will not work if the hosts are different. When this is the case you will get an error statement of the type

> svn: The repository at 'TO_PATH' has uuid '47378e3f-18ec-4688-a92c-46777710830a', but the WC has 'c6f1d636-074b-0410-81ee-9b5c3d6808e7

In this case, the only solution is to do a fresh `import` to the new repo.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the `switch --relocate FROM TO [PATH...]` command.

Comment: From **svn help switch**:
    `The '--relocate' option is deprecated. This syntax is equivalent to 'svn relocate FROM-PREFIX TO-PREFIX [PATH]'`